# Iterating over "Self" Variable in Class (Attribute Error)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm not sure if the title even makes sense but basically I have a class that keeps track of friends (like an address book), and I'm at the part where I need to create a function that adds friends to a set of existing names. So I've got the beginning of my code as:

```
class SocialAddressBook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.book= []


    def addName(self, name, address):
        self.book.append([name, address, set()])
        """Adds name to address book, with address and no friends"""
```

which runs fine. and then the part that gives me `'list' object has no attribute 'list'` error:

```
def addFriend(self, name, friend):
    for k in range(len(self.book.list[k])):
        if self.book[k][0] == name:
```

my idea was to iterate over a list and add onto the existing list, but syntax is definitely throwing me for a loop (no pun intended) and I'm not sure how I should go about this now.

some test code:

```
a.addFriend('Fred', 'Barb'); a.addFriend('Fred', 'Sue')
a.addFriend('Barb', 'Jane'); a.addFriend('Jane', 'Emma')
a.addFriend('Jane', 'Mary'); a.addFriend('Emma', 'Lisa')
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you doing `self.book.list`, I think think lists have a `list` property.

Comment: Usually you don't need an index to iterate over collections in Python. Simply `for book_name, address, friends in self.book:` and then `if book_name == name:` would do, depending on what comes after. Probably `friends.add(friend)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop in your `addFriend` method is incorrect.  Specifically, `self.book.list[k]`.

First off, `self.book` is a list, and lists do not have a `list` property.  Second, you can't use `k` there as it does not yet exist.

If you want to loop over a list, why not just do that?  You don't need to use `range()`.

```
for book in self.book:
    if book[0] == name:
        pass
```

Comment: You're welcome!  For more advanced coding, you can actually *unpack* the values in the `for` loop.  `for b_name, b_address, b_set in self.book:` then instead of using `book[0]`, you can use `b_name`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, your solution should be implemented using a dictionary instead of a list to improve performance of your address book. Adding names is trivial, and other than the error checking involved, adding friends is also trivial. For a more complete solution, a `remove_name` method has been added showing how to correctly remove someone.

```
import collections


def main():
    book = SocialAddressBook()
    # Add people to the address book.
    book.add_name('Fred', 'fred@gmail.com')
    book.add_name('Barb', 'barb@gmail.com')
    book.add_name('Jane', 'jane@gmail.com')
    book.add_name('Emma', 'emma@gmail.com')
    book.add_name('Sue', 'sue@gmail.com')
    book.add_name('Mary', 'mary@gmail.com')
    book.add_name('Lisa', 'lisa@gmail.com')
    # Add friends connections in the address book.
    book.add_friend('Fred', 'Barb')
    book.add_friend('Fred', 'Sue')
    book.add_friend('Barb', 'Jane')
    book.add_friend('Jane', 'Emma')
    book.add_friend('Jane', 'Mary')
    book.add_friend('Emma', 'Lisa')


class SocialAddressBook:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__book = {}

    def add_name(self, name, address):
        """Adds name to address book with address and no friends."""
        self.__book[name] = BookEntry(address, set())

    def add_friend(self, name, friend):
        """Adds a friend to the person referenced by name."""
        if friend not in self.__book:
            raise ValueError(f'{friend!r} is not in the address book yet')
        self.__book[name].friends.add(friend)

    def remove_name(self, name):
        """Completely delete someone from the address book."""
        del self.__book[name]
        for book_entry in self.__book.values():
            book_entry.friends.discard(name)


BookEntry = collections.namedtuple('BookEntry', 'address, friends')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please read [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) soon if possible. Code written in Python should conform to the style guide to promote maintainability and to encourage others to read your code and answer your questions. In the future, please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem before asking your question.